# Screensaver with Flash running on win and mac

Tags: flash, screensaver, projector

I was asked to create a screensaver capable to run on both win and mac. I am ActionScript developer, so I prefer to solve this using Flash/SWF. I know this is possible using several tools:

- Projectors such as Zinc or SWF Studio (os independent, $$$)
- Converters creating screensavers that use the Flash Player (one converter per os necessary, requires Flash Player on user machine, freeware)
- Adobe Air created screensavers (os independent, requires Air on user machine, no costs)

I do not have control over the machines the screensaver will run. So everything needs to be simple and safe. I would go for option 2, but I am not sure if the tools I discovered are reliable.

THE QUESTION

- What tool you recommend to create the screensaver descibed using existing SWF files?
- Is there another (single) tool to create the screensaver without using Flash/AS/SWF?

Comment: I have used http://www.screentime.com/ in the past, with fairly good results, although not perfect with regards to settings panels and such in the end product, the screeensavers. But I would say Screentime is good in a does-what-it-says-on-the-box kind of way.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. The job will make less than the software does cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any free/custom way of making a screensaver that works on both Windows and Mac. For Windows you can easily make one yourself by wrapping the Flash ActiveX, or you can use [instantstorm](http://www.instantstorm.com/), which is free.

Comment: instantstorm is currently my choice together with http://www.video-flash.de/swf-screensaver-for-mac/

Comment: Give you the check since no other peoples have contributed here :-)